# Portfolio optimization with quadprog for specific returns results in "constraints are inconsistent, no solution"

Tags: optimization, constraints, portfolio, quadratic-programming, quadprog

I read some posts about portfolio optimization with quadprog and i learned many tricks from this platform. Now i am trying to optimize a portfolio of 03 stocks with quadprog under the constrains i.e.,.

- Weights must sum to 1
- No short selling
- portfolio return = 2%
- Each stock weight must not exceed 50% of the total weight

The covariancce matrix for my 3 stock is

```
Dmat = matrix(c(0.0119, 0.0071, -0.0023,0.0071, 0.0093, 
            -0.0006,-0.0023,-0.0006,0.0066), nrow = 3)
```

The stock returns/colmeans are stored in Dvec

```
Dvec = c(0.0373, 0.0173, 0.0261)
```

I used the code and procedure mentioned in this post [Portfolio Optimization constraints Matrix/bvec explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34143734/portfolio-optimization-constraints-matrix-bvec-explanation/34158676#34158676). I also read the similar posts [Portfolio Optimization constraints Matrix/bvec explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34143734/portfolio-optimization-constraints-matrix-bvec-explanation) and [Constraints on weight in portfolio optimization using quadprog package in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16562379/constraints-on-weight-in-portfolio-optimization-using-quadprog-package-in-r?rq=1) So the code i tried looks like this

```
N = 3
total.returns = 0.02
lo = rep(0,N)
up = rep(0.50,N)
A = rbind(rep(1,N), dvec, diag(N), -diag(N))
A = t(A)
B = c(1,total.returns, lo, -up)
neq = 1
qp = solve.QP(Dmat, dvec, A, B,neq)
qp$solution
```

I start the analysis with two equalities i.e. one for hundred percent investment and the other for portfolio returns. I read it in another post that the returns may be causing problem such that the returns we are looking for are not possible with the current data and constrains. So i also change the return to different level but it does not work so i relaxed the return equality and use neq=1. Still it is not working. I also tried different weights constrains on individual stocks i.e. i tried to change upper limit (up) from 5% to 80%.
NOTE: When i write the amat and bvev with out the total returns then the code works. i.e. when i use A and B as

```
A = rbind(rep(1,N), diag(N), -diag(N))
B = c(1, lo, -up)
```

instead of

```
A = rbind(rep(1,N), dvec, diag(N), -diag(N))   and 
B = c(1,total.returns, lo, -up).
```

My question is why i am getting the "constraints are inconsistent, no solution" when i use my code mentioned above?
I will be thankful if some one can figure out what mistake i am doing? Thank you so much in advance to all of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am trying to understand your data:

```
total.returns = 2.0
```

this means I want a 200% portfolio return with instruments that have a return of

```
Dvec = c(0.0373, 0.0173, 0.0261)
```

or between 1.7% and 3.7%. That is not so easy.

Comment: Dear Erwin Kalvelagen thank you so much. Yes you are hundred percent right. i was aiming at 2% returns. I should have wriiten this as 0.02 in bvec.